# Display Progress bar while copying files in only SWT not in jface

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to create one installation wizard in SWT.

I have some code that displays a progress bar while copying files.

```
 import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlEvent;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlListener;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseListener;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
    import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;
    import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.FontData;
    import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DirectoryDialog;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

    public class SWT_Second {

        public static Button b2;
        public static Composite directoryInstComposite;
        public static Composite workComposite;
        public static Composite copyFilesComposite;
        public static Label dir_entry_label;
        public static Text dir_entry_text;
        public static Label dir_info_label;
        public static Button dir_next_button;
        public static Button dir_cancel_button;
        public static Button copy_next_button;
        public static Button copy_cancel_button;        
        public static Shell shell;
        public static ProgressBar pbar;
        public static Display display;
        public static File currentDir;
        public static boolean copyFlag=false;
        public static boolean actualCopyFlag=false;
        public static boolean copySuccess=true;
        public static int runWithoutAdminRights=-1;

        public static Combo c1;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                display = new Display();
            shell = new Shell(display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN |SWT.MAX| SWT.CENTER | SWT.SYSTEM_MODAL | SWT.
    APPLICATION_MODAL);  
            shell.setSize(450,348);
            shell.setLocation(250, 150);
            shell.setText("Installer!");
            shell.setLayout(new FormLayout());

            final Image HKimage0=new Image(display,SWT_Second.class.getResourceAsStream("Img/d.png"));
            shell.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                    e.gc.drawImage(HKimage0, 0, 0);
                }
            });
            shell.setImage(HKimage0);
            Composite headerComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
            headerComposite.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));
            FormData shellFormData = new FormData();

            shellFormData.top=new FormAttachment(0,0);
            shellFormData.left=new FormAttachment(00,0);

            shellFormData.width=1364;
            shellFormData.height=60;

            headerComposite.setLayoutData(shellFormData);
            Canvas prodName = new Canvas(headerComposite, SWT.NONE);
            prodName.setBounds(6,6, 135,50);
            prodName.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(headerComposite, SWT.NONE);
            canvas.setSize(500,60);

            canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                    e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
                    e.gc.drawRectangle(3,3,437, 56);
                }
            });
            final Image HKimage=new Image(display,SWT_Second.class.getResourceAsStream("Img/Logo_True_Colors.png"));

            prodName.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                    e.gc.drawImage(HKimage, 0, 0);
                }
            });

            workComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
            workComposite.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));

            FormData shellFormData1 = new FormData();
            shellFormData1.top=new FormAttachment(0,53);
            shellFormData1.left=new FormAttachment(00,0);
            shellFormData1.width=1364;
            shellFormData1.height=1000;
            workComposite.setLayoutData(shellFormData1);

            Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(workComposite, SWT.NONE);
            canvas1.setSize(500,230);
            canvas1.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));
            canvas1.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                    e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
                    e.gc.drawRectangle(3,10,437, 219);
                }
            });
            Canvas canvas2= new Canvas(workComposite, SWT.NONE);
            canvas2.setSize(500,280);
            canvas2.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));
            canvas2.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {

                    e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
                    e.gc.drawRectangle(3,233,437, 31);

                }
            });

            final Label inst_wel_label = new Label(canvas1,SWT.NONE);
            inst_wel_label.setText("Welcome to Setup");
            Font boldFont = new Font( inst_wel_label.getDisplay(), new FontData( "TimesNewRoman", 16, SWT.BOLD ) );
            inst_wel_label.setFont( boldFont );

            inst_wel_label.setLocation(65, 50);
            inst_wel_label.setSize(245, 25);
            inst_wel_label.setAlignment(2);

            final Label inst_type_label = new Label(canvas1,SWT.NONE);
            inst_type_label.setText("Select Installation Type");
            inst_type_label.setLocation(65,100);
            inst_type_label.setSize(123, 25);
            inst_type_label.setAlignment(2);

            c1 = new Combo(canvas1, SWT.READ_ONLY);
            c1.setBounds(205,100, 130,65);
            c1.select(0);

            String items[] = { "Dev User", "Operations User"};
            c1.setItems(items);
            c1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    if (c1.getText().equals("Dev User")) {
                        InstallUser="Dev User";
                    } else if (c1.getText().equals("Operations User")) {
                        InstallUser="Operations User";
                    } else {
                        InstallUser="NONE";
                    }
                }
            });
   final Label inst_start_label = new Label(canvas1,SWT.NONE);
            inst_start_label.setText("To start installation process, click Go");
            inst_start_label.setLocation(65, 140);
            inst_start_label.setSize(200,15);

            Button b = new Button(canvas2, SWT.NONE);
            b.setText("Go");
            b.setSize(50, 20);
            b.setLocation(310,240);

            Button b1 = new Button(canvas2, SWT.NONE);
            b1.setText("Cancel");
            b1.setSize(50, 20);
            b1.setLocation(365,240);

            b1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0) {
                }
            });
            i = 0;
            workComposite.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                @Override
                public void paintControl(PaintEvent arg0) {
                    System.out.println("Inside Paint Listener " + new Date());
                    if(i==0) {
                        i++;
                        Date dt = null;
                        SimpleDateFormat st = null;
                        File checkAdminRightsFile = null;
                        try {
                            dt = new Date();
                            st = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                            String dd = st.format(dt);
                            checkAdminRightsFile = new File("C:\\Installer".concat(dd));
                            RandomAccessFile checkAdminRights = new RandomAccessFile(checkAdminRightsFile, "rw");
                            checkAdminRights.close();
                            runWithoutAdminRights=SWT.NO;
                        }
                        catch (Exception fs) {
                            if(fs.getMessage().contains("Access is denied")) {
                                MessageBox DirMsgBox = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.ICON_QUESTION | SWT.YES | SWT.NO);
                                runWithoutAdminRights = DirMsgBox.open();
                                if(runWithoutAdminRights==SWT.NO) {
                                    MessageBox DirMsgBox1 = new MessageBox(shell);
                                    DirMsgBox1.setText("Aborting Installation");
                                    DirMsgBox1.open();
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                            } else {
                                MessageBox DirMsgBox1 = new MessageBox(shell);
                                DirMsgBox1.setMessage("Encountered error while creating file " + 
    checkAdminRightsFile.getAbsoluteFile() +" : " + fs.getMessage() + "\n Aborting the 
    process for now");                  
                                DirMsgBox1.open();
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        }    
                        try {
                            checkAdminRightsFile.delete();
                        } catch (Exception ot) {
                            MessageBox DirMsgBox1 = new MessageBox(shell);
                            DirMsgBox1.setMessage("Encountered error while deleting the temp file " + 
    checkAdminRightsFile.getAbsoluteFile() +" : " + ot.getMessage() + "\n Aborting the process 
    for now");                  
                            DirMsgBox1.open();
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            b.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    if(c1.getSelectionIndex()==-1) {
                        MessageBox DirMsgBox = new MessageBox(shell);
                        DirMsgBox.setText("Please select Installation Type ");
                        DirMsgBox.setMessage("Installation type is not selected - please select to proceed ...");
                        DirMsgBox.open();
                    } else {
                        b2.setVisible(true);
                        workComposite.setVisible(false);
                        directoryInstComposite.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    workComposite.setVisible(false);
                    directoryInstComposite.setVisible(true);
                }
            });

            directoryInstComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);  
            directoryInstComposite.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));    
            FormData FD_InstPath = new FormData();
            FD_InstPath.top=new FormAttachment(0,53);
            FD_InstPath.left=new FormAttachment(00,0);
            FD_InstPath.width=1364;
            FD_InstPath.height=1000;
            directoryInstComposite.setLayoutData(FD_InstPath);    
            directoryInstComposite.setVisible(false);

            Canvas canvas3 = new Canvas(directoryInstComposite, SWT.NONE);
            canvas3.setSize(500,230);
            canvas3.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));
            canvas3.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                    e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
                    e.gc.drawRectangle(3,10,437, 219);
                }
            });
            Canvas canvas4= new Canvas(directoryInstComposite, SWT.NONE);
            canvas4.setSize(500,280);
            canvas4.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));
            canvas4.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                    e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
                    e.gc.drawRectangle(3,233,437, 31);
                }
            });  
            dir_info_label = new Label(canvas3, SWT.NONE);
            dir_info_label.setText("Browse for Configuration Directory...");
            Font boldFont3 = new Font( dir_info_label.getDisplay(), new FontData( "TimesNewRoman", 10, SWT.BOLD ) );
            dir_info_label.setFont(boldFont3);
            dir_info_label.setSize(350, 19);
            dir_info_label.setLocation(75,25);

            dir_entry_label = new Label(canvas3, SWT.NONE);
            dir_entry_label.setText("Location:");
            dir_entry_label.setSize(60, 20);
            dir_entry_label.setLocation(18,65); 

            dir_entry_text = new Text(canvas3, SWT.BORDER );

            dir_entry_text.setText("Enter Directory");
            dir_entry_text.setSize(270,19);
            dir_entry_text.setLocation(75,65);
            dir_browse_button = new Button(canvas3, SWT.PUSH);
            dir_browse_button.setText("Browse...");
            dir_browse_button.setSize(54,19);
            dir_browse_button.setLocation(350,65);
            dir_browse_button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                    DirectoryDialog dlg = new DirectoryDialog(shell);
                    // Set the initial filter path according
                    // to anything they've selected or typed in
                    dlg.setFilterPath(dir_entry_text.getText());
                    System.out.println("dlg.setFilterPath: "+dir_entry_text.getText());
                    // Change the title bar text
                    dlg.setText("SWT's DirectoryDialog");
                    // Customizable message displayed in the dialog
                    dlg.setMessage("Select a directory");
                    // Calling open() will open and run the dialog. It will return the selected directory, or null if user cancels
                    String dir = dlg.open();
                    if (dir != null) {
                        // Set the text box to the new selection
                        dir_entry_text.setText(dir);
                    }
                }
            }); 
            dir_next_button = new Button(canvas4, SWT.NONE);
            dir_next_button.setSize(50, 20);
            dir_next_button.setLocation(310, 240);
            dir_next_button.setText("Install");

            dir_cancel_button = new Button(canvas4, SWT.NONE);
            dir_cancel_button.setSize(50, 20);
            dir_cancel_button.setLocation(365, 240);
            dir_cancel_button.setText("Cancel");

            dir_next_button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

                @Override
                public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    try {
                        if(dir_entry_text.getText()!=null && !dir_entry_text.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            BaseDir = new File(dir_entry_text.getText());
                            if(!BaseDir.exists() && !BaseDir.isDirectory()) {
                                MessageBox DirMsgBox = new MessageBox(shell);
                                DirMsgBox.setText("Directory does not exist!!!! ");         
                                DirMsgBox.open();                   
                            } else {
                                directoryInstComposite.setVisible(false);
                                copyFilesComposite.setVisible(true);
                                pbar.setVisible(true);
                                (new SWT_Second()).new ProgressBarClass(display, pbar).start(); 
                                System.out.println("Text in dir_entry_text is  : " + dir_entry_text.getText());

                                String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                                System.out.println("Current directory is : " + workingDir);
                                currentDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                                try {
                                    logFile = new File(BaseDir.getAbsolutePath().concat(File.separator).concat(
    "Insaller.log"));
                                    if(logFile.exists()) {
                                        Date curr = new Date();
    ".").concat(curr.toString())));

                                    }                   
                                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    MessageBox DirMsgBox = new MessageBox(shell);
                                    DirMsgBox.setMessage("Exception while creating log file : " + ex.getMessage() + 
    "\n Aborting the process..");                   
                                    DirMsgBox.open();       
                                    System.exit(0);
                                // Remove this comment - commented for runnig from eclipse
                                //copyFiles(currentDir,BaseDir);
                                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        try {
                                            File SetupDir = new File(SWT_Second.currentDir.getAbsolutePath().concat(File
    .separator).concat("setup"));
                                            copyFiles(SetupDir,BaseDir);

                                            actualCopyFlag=true;
                                        } 
                                        catch (IOException io) {
                                            SWT_Second.actualCopyFlag=false;
                                            SWT_Second.copySuccess=false;


                                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                                            SWT_Second.actualCopyFlag=false;
                                            SWT_Second.copySuccess=false;
                                            ex.printStackTrace();
                                            MessageBox DirMsgBox = new MessageBox(shell);
                                            DirMsgBox.setText("Generic problem!!!! ");
                                            DirMsgBox.setMessage("Some problem occured .. aborting .. check logs 
    for details! \n" + ex.getMessage() );                   
                                            DirMsgBox.open();

                                            System.exit(0);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                t.start();
                            }
                            System.out.println("Copy Progress bar is complete ");
                        } else {
                            MessageBox DirMsgBox = new MessageBox(shell);
                            DirMsgBox.setText("Please select a directory");
                            DirMsgBox.setMessage("Please select a directory to Install ..");                    
                            DirMsgBox.open();
                        }
                    }  catch (Exception gen) {
                    gen.printStackTrace();
                    MessageBox DirMsgBox = new MessageBox(shell);
                    DirMsgBox.setMessage("Some problem occured .. aborting .. check logs for details! \n" + gen.
    getMessage() );                 
                    DirMsgBox.open();

                }
                }
                @Override
                public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0) {

                    if(dir_entry_text.getText()!=null && !dir_entry_text.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                    }           
                }
            });

            copyFilesComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);     
            copyFilesComposite.setLayoutData(FD_InstPath);    
            copyFilesComposite.setVisible(false);

            Canvas canvas5 = new Canvas(copyFilesComposite, SWT.NONE);
            canvas5.setSize(500,230);
            canvas5.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));
            canvas5.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                    e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
                    e.gc.drawRectangle(3,10,437, 219);
                }
            });
            Canvas canvas6= new Canvas(copyFilesComposite, SWT.NONE);
            canvas6.setSize(500,280);
            canvas6.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND));
            canvas6.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                    e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GRAY));
                    e.gc.drawRectangle(3,233,437, 31);
                }

            pbar = new ProgressBar(canvas5,SWT.NULL);
            pbar.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
            pbar.setMinimum(0);
            pbar.setMaximum(30);
            pbar.setLocation(100,90);
            pbar.setSize(280,14);

            copy_next_button = new Button(canvas6, SWT.NONE);
            copy_next_button.setSize(50, 20);
            copy_next_button.setLocation(310, 240);
            copy_next_button.setText("Next");       
            canvas6.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                @Override
                public void paintControl(PaintEvent arg0) {
                    if(copySuccess) {
                        if(copyFlag && actualCopyFlag) {
                            copy_next_button.setEnabled(true);
                        } 
                    } else {
                        MessageBox DirMsgBox = new MessageBox(shell);
                        DirMsgBox.setText("Error in Copy Operation");
                        DirMsgBox.setMessage("Please check if the directory has write permissions and does not have 
    Files already present \n please delete the exisitng Files and retry \n Aborting now.."
     );                 
                        DirMsgBox.open();
                            System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            });   
            public static void copyFiles(File srcDir, File destDir)  throws IOException{
            String strSubDestDir=null;
            File subDestDir=null;

            for (File f : srcDir.listFiles()) {
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println("It is a directory");
                    strSubDestDir = destDir.getAbsolutePath().concat(File.separator).concat(f.getName());
                    subDestDir = new File(strSubDestDir);
                    if( !subDestDir.exists() ) {
                        subDestDir.mkdir();
                    }
                    copyFiles(f, subDestDir);
                } else {    
                    System.out.println("It is simple a file");
    Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()).toString() + " to "+  
    Paths.get(destDir.getAbsolutePath()).toString());
                    File newFile = new File(destDir.getAbsolutePath().concat(File.separator).concat(f.getName()));
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("COUNT : "+count);
                    if(f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Dt.jar") || f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ProgressViwer.jar")) {
                        if(f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Dt.jar") && InstallUser.equalsIgnoreCase("Dt Dev User")) {
                            Files.copy(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()), Paths.get(newFile.getAbsolutePath()), 
    StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
                        } 
                        if (f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ProgressViwer.jar") && InstallUser.equalsIgnoreCase(
    "Operations User")) {
                            Files.copy(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()), Paths.get(newFile.getAbsolutePath()), 
    StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);

                        } 
                    } else {
                        Files.copy(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()), Paths.get(newFile.getAbsolutePath()), 
    StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            class ProgressBarClass extends Thread {
            private Display display;
            private ProgressBar progressBar;
            public ProgressBarClass(Display display, ProgressBar progressBar) 
            {
                this.display = display;
                this.progressBar = progressBar;
            }
            public void run()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    }
                    display.asyncExec(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            if (progressBar.isDisposed())
                            {                 
                                return;
                            }
                            System.out.println("progressBar.getSelection() is @@==> " + progressBar.
    getSelection());
                            progressBar.setSelection(progressBar.getSelection() + 1);
                            System.out.println("Completed");
                        }
                    });
                }
                copyFlag=true;       
            }
        }
    }
```

My code is displaying the progress bar, but the files are not being copied.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

I am trying with sample code.

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell (display);

        shell.open ();
        File srcFile=new File("C:\\Users\\aa00333221\\Desktop\\s");
        File destFile=new File("C:\\Users\\aa00333221\\Desktop\\S2");

        String[] files=srcFile.list();
        System.out.println("files :"+files);

        f1=numberOfFiles(srcFile);
        System.out.println("Count: "+f1);

        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar (shell, SWT.SMOOTH);
        bar.setLocation(100,90);
        bar.setSize(280,14);
        bar.setMaximum(f1);

        for (String name : files) {
            System.out.println("File name: " + name);

        }

        for(int i=0;i<f1;i++){
            System.out.println("Files[i]: "+files[i]);
strSubDestDir = srcFile.getAbsolutePath().concat(File.separator).concat(files[i]);
            subDestDir = new File(strSubDestDir);
File newFile = new File(destFile.getAbsolutePath().concat(File.separator).concat(files[i]));
FileUtils.copyFile(subDestDir, newFile);
            bar.setSelection (i+1);
            int x=i+1;
            System.out.println("bar.setSelection (i+1): "+x );
            System.out.println("copy done for "+strSubDestDir +"to "+newFile);
        }
        while (!shell.isDisposed ())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }

    public static int numberOfFiles(File srcDir) {
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("calling NumbeerOfFiles Method");
        File[] listFiles = srcDir.listFiles();
        for(int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++){
            if (listFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                count += numberOfFiles(listFiles[i]);
            } else if (listFiles[i].isFile()) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
This is working for files only, not for subfolders.
Have to display the progress bar while copying folders and subfolders also.
```

Comment: You could use a `IRunnableWithProgress`. Have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12987522/1740724).

Comment: You will have better results createing a simpler smaller example of code,Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182114/how-does-one-show-progress-of-a-java-file-copy-operation-in-icefaces , where the system out is you can basically update your progress bar. Keep in mind you don't actually want to tie your copy directly to progress bar (GUI to Back end). Your best bet is to create events which fire on property changes to update the gui.

Comment: @Baz.. Its my mistake i forget to mention. SWT is only allowed, Not jface.

Comment: @mohamedasif Any feedback to my answer?

Comment: apologies for delay. Thanks for your answer. I am getting errors only. Still tying.

Comment: @mohamedasif What kind of errors?

Comment: @Baz invalid thread access

Comment: @mohamedasif Looks like you're trying to manipulate the UI from a background thread. Read [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Why_do_I_get_an_invalid_thread_access_exception%3F) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980316/invalid-thread-access-error-with-java-swt) for more help.

Comment: @mohamedasif This line is the problem: `String[] files = srcFile.list();`. You're only getting the files in the root directory. You could look at a the [file walker API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77720/discussion-between-mohamed-asif-and-baz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static ProgressBar bar;
    static int pb=0;
public static void copyFiles(final File srcFile,File destFile)  throws IOException{
        String mkDir= null;
        File mkDir1=null;
        String cpDir= null;
        File cpDir1=null;


        System.out.println("INSIDE METHOD :");

        {
            z=srcFile.listFiles();
            System.out.println("INSIDE FIRST LOOP");

            for (File f : srcFile.listFiles()) {
                if (f.isFile()) {
                    pb++;
                    System.out.println("File name ZZ: "+f.getName());
                    String sSrcDir=srcFile.getAbsolutePath().concat(File.separator).concat(f.getName());
                    System.out.println("sSrcDir: "+sSrcDir);
                    File sSrcFile=new File(sSrcDir);

                    File newFile = new File(destFile.getAbsolutePath().concat(File.separator).concat(f.getName()));
                    System.out.println("newFile: "+newFile);

                    FileUtils.copyFile(sSrcFile, newFile);
                    bar.setSelection (pb+1);
                    int x=pb+1;
                    System.out.println("bar.setSelection (j+1): "+x );
                    System.out.println("copy done for "+strSubDestDir +"to "+newFile);
                    //FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, destFile);
                }
                else if(f.isDirectory())
                {
                    System.out.println("INSIDE DIRECTORY LOOP");
                    System.out.println("It is a directory"+f.getName());
                    cpDir=srcFile.getAbsolutePath().concat(File.separator).concat(f.getName());
                    cpDir1=new File(cpDir);
                    System.out.println("cpDir:  "+cpDir);
                    mkDir = destDir.getAbsolutePath().concat(File.separator).concat(f.getName());

                    mkDir1 = new File(mkDir);
                    System.out.println("mkDir : "+mkDir);
                    if( !mkDir1.exists() ) {
                        mkDir1.mkdir();
                    }
                    copyFiles(cpDir1, mkDir1);
                    //FileUtils.copyDirectory(cpDir1, mkDir1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure where exactly you're having difficulties, but here is some code that processes a directory file by file and updates a `ProgressBar`. You should be able to modify it according to your needs:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Start copying");

    final ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(shell, SWT.NONE);

    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            String path = new DirectoryDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN).open();

            if (path != null && !"".equals(path))
            {
                File file = new File(path);

                final File[] files = file.listFiles();

                if(files == null)
                    return;

                bar.setMinimum(0);
                bar.setMaximum(files.length);
                bar.setSelection(0);

                Runnable run = new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        for(File f : files)
                        {
                            System.out.println(f);

                            display.asyncExec(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    bar.setSelection(bar.getSelection() + 1);
                                }
                            });

                            try
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        display.asyncExec(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                bar.setSelection(0);
                            }
                        });
                        System.out.println("DONE");
                    }
                };

                new Thread(run).start();
            }
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}
```